# Passar dados da controller para o EJS

Tags: mysql, express.js

Preciso passar os dados obtidos, por uma query no banco de dados, para o meu template EJS com o objetivo de manipular esses valores.

Meu código atual está assim

```
router.get('/devreport', redirectLogin, (req, res) => {
    //todo trocar o valor para o codigo do sg ao invés de 1. mockado para finalizar
    let cod_sg = 1;
    let heuristic_values = [];
    let selectQuery = `SELECT * 
                        FROM formulario
                        WHERE cod_sg = ?`

    let queryValues = [cod_sg];

    execSQLQuery(selectQuery, queryValues)
        .then(dbResponse => {
                heuristic_values.push({
                    values: dbResponse[0].heuristic_responses
                });            
            console.log(heuristic_values);
            res.render('../views/devreport.ejs', { heuristic_values });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            console.log(req.session.userId);
            res.json('fuck');
        });

    /* req.session.cod_sg = null; */

    res.render('../views/devreport.ejs');
});
```

Resultado do console.log(heuristic_values);

```
[ { values: '{"likert-one": "strong_agree", "likert-six": "strong_agree", "likert-ten": "strong_disagree", "likert-two": "agree", "likert-five": "agree", "likert-four": "neutral", "likert-nine": "strong_agree", "likert-eight": "neutral", "likert-seven": "neutral", "likert-three": "strong_disagree", "likert-eleven": "agree", "likert-twelve": "strong_disagree", "likert-fifteen": "neutral", "likert-sixteen": "neutral", "likert-fourteen": "neutral", "likert-thirteen": "neutral", "likert-seventeen": "neutral"}' } ]
```

Entretanto, quando eu chego na página a qual eu renderizei esses valores, tenho o seguinte retorno

```
ReferenceError: C:\Users\konex\Videos\ExpertSystem\views\devreport.ejs:14
    12| 

    13|     <ul>

 >> 14|             <%  const responses = heuristic_values %>

    15| 

    16|     </ul>

    17| 


heuristic_values is not defined
    at eval (eval at compile (C:\Users\konex\Videos\ExpertSystem\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:618:12), <anonymous>:11:27)
    at returnedFn (C:\Users\konex\Videos\ExpertSystem\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:653:17)
    at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\konex\Videos\ExpertSystem\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:251:36)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\konex\Videos\ExpertSystem\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:482:10)
    at View.render (C:\Users\konex\Videos\ExpertSystem\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (C:\Users\konex\Videos\ExpertSystem\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (C:\Users\konex\Videos\ExpertSystem\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\konex\Videos\ExpertSystem\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1008:7)
    at router.get (C:\Users\konex\Videos\ExpertSystem\controllers\home_controller.js:248:9)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\konex\Videos\ExpertSystem\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Você está apenas passando o conteúdo `heuristic_values` na renderização do ejs e não a variável em si, se você quer acessar uma variável na sua view você deve especificar o seu nome da seguinte maneira:

```
res.render('../views/devreport.ejs', { 'heuristic_values' : heuristic_values });
```

Aqui é passado uma variável `'heuristic_values'` nomeada.

Quando você passou apenas os o `heuristic_values` você passou apenas o conteúdo dele, para tirar a prova e entender a forma de passagem de dados na sua view(devreports.ejs) no seu código como está em vez de colocar sua variável coloque um dos valores contidos, como `likert-one`, você verá o conteúdo ser impresso na tela.

Comment: cara, fiz as alterações que você solicitou e continuo com o mesmo problema. Ao colocar <%  const responses = likert-one %>, o erro atualiza para likert is not defined

Comment: Cara foi só um exemplo, mas faça o seguinte na linha que você renderiza o ejs,`res.render('../views/devreport.ejs', { heuristic_values });` você altera para  `
res.render('../views/devreport.ejs', { 'heuristic_values' : heuristic_values });`, na sua view você coloca `<%  const responses = heuristic_values %>` agora deve funcionar

Comment: pô, men, eu tinha feito exatamente isso ai :(
muito obrigado por tentar me ajudar

Answer (score 0):

identifiquei o problema. Testei e está OK!

O motivo era: eu estava usando o res.render duas vezes.
Na primeira vez, eu renderizava com a variável heuristic_values.
Na segunda vez, eu renderizava sem. Por conta disso, perdia-se a referência.

```
res.render('../views/devreport.ejs', { heuristic_values });

res.render('../views/devreport.ejs');
```